# Test if getJSONArray is null or not

Tags: java, android, json

My code extract results of JSONObject, but, sometimes, the i value don't begin to 1, and i have an error like that :

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for 1
```

My code :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
       for(int i=1;i<=14;i++) {

            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray(""+i);
        extraction(arr, i);
       }
```

I want to test before the extraction if the object code (i) exists or not. How i can do this ?

Comment: I may be wrong but should not it be zero based index ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use `obj.optJSONArray(name)` the response will be null if the name does not exists.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
   for(int i=1;i<=14;i++) {

        JSONArray arr = obj.optJSONArray(""+i);
        if(arr != null) {
              extraction(arr, i);
        }
   }
```

Comment: This line : JSONArray arr = obj.optJSONArray(""+i); 
is responsible to the error, and stop the code. It never arrive to the "if". How i can test if it's null ?

Comment: you need to understand the difference betwen getJSONArray and optJSONArray. The first crashes if the key is not present, the second one returns null, which you can test.

Answer (score 4):

use `JSONObject.optJSONArray(key).`

As indicated in the documentation, it returns null in case the key is not present.

Also, your JSON structure seems weird. Why do you have numeric ordered keys in an object? shouldn't that be an Array?

Comment: That a particularity of my code, i need a int to retrieve a data in the database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use .length() for check the return null of JSONArray.
Use .isNull("xxx") instead of .length(), the example is below:

```
JSONArray magazineLove  = null;
if(!socialBook.getJSONObject(i).isNull("MagazineLove"))
{
    magazineLove = socialBook.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("MagazineLove");                
}
```

Aey.Sakon