# How to match when array is null

Tags: android, jsonparser

This is my code.

```
                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("restaurents");

                        if(!jarray.equals("null")) {
                            //District value is not null

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), " null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
```

And this is my json responce.

{
    "status": "success",
    "restaurents": null
}

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: if(jarray != null ) i think u should try this thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if getJSONArray is null or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110066/test-if-getjsonarray-is-null-or-not)

Comment: not getting toast when array is null

Answer (score 2):

```
if(jarray != null){
      Toast.makeText(getContext(), "not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}else{
      Toast.makeText(getContext(), " null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: not getting toast when array is null

Comment: then cursor is not going to this line

Comment: solution ? i have tried almost everything i cud do.

Comment: can u show the code

Comment: JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("restaurents");

                            if(jarray != null){
                           
                                rcview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                tvempty.setVisibility(View.GONE);else{
                               rcview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               tvempty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

Answer (score 1):

JsonArray return object and you are treating jArray as `String`. So you need to treat jArray as object:-

```
if(jarray != null ) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), " null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: not getting toast when array is null

Comment: what error it shows?

Comment: There are no error but else part is not executing

Comment: can u show the code

Answer (score 0):

Currently u are checking like this

`if(!jarray.equals("null"))`

where it treats "null" as string so remove `" "`

Try like this

```
if(!jarray.equals(null))
```

or try like this

```
if (jarray.length() ==0 )
```

check the size of array

Comment: i have checked in both conditions